# Is there a plugin for java annotation which provides a feature like @NoGetter and @NoSetter?

Tags: java, annotation, intellij

I know about lombok which provides @Getter @Setter. But I have to specify this for each property. Considering I have a big application and most most of the v

Comment: Your question is cut o.....

Answer (score 1):

Use in this way with lombok

```
@Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
private String name;
```